# How to print of the text between the last occurence of a pair of patterns?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am trying to print the lines between the last occurrence of two patterns into another file using sed. For example, if file1 contains the following:

```
StartPattern
1
2
3
EndPattern
4
5
StartPattern
6
7
8
EndPattern
9
10
StartPattern
11
12
13
EndPattern
14
15
```

I would like the output to be:

```
11
12
13
```

How can I do this with sed?

Comment: `cat file|sed -n 'H; /^StartPattern/h; ${g;p;}' |sed '1d' |sed '/EndPattern/q' |sed '$ d'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With single **awk** process:

```
awk '/StartPattern/{ f=1;r=""; next }f && /EndPattern/{f=0}
     f{ r=(r=="")? $0: r RS $0 }END{ print r }' file > output
```

---

`output` file contents:

```
11
12
13
```

---

Alternative **tac** + **awk** solution:

```
tac file | awk '/StartPattern/{exit}/EndPattern/{f=1;next}f' | tac > output
```

Comment: This works if the End Pattern is the last line of the file. I realize my original post (which is now editted) was misleading. How can I only extract what's in between the patterns and not the rest of the file if there are lines below the last EndPattern?

Comment: @A.B, it will work even if `EndPattern` is not the last line. You need to test

Comment: Your first answer (tac+awk) prints: 11 12 13 14 15. However, your new answer (single awk) gives the correct output.

Comment: @A.B, I can not see the issue. Look here https://ibb.co/bTqUYk

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file |sed -n 'H; /^StartPattern/h; ${g;p;}' |sed -e '1d' -e '/EndPattern/q' |sed '$ d'
```

Answer (score -1):

A file contain:
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern2

Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern2
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern2

So here Patern1 come multiple times before  Patern2 come.
I want to get the lines between Patern1 and Patern2. Not the line between Patern1 and Patern1.

Just like:
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern2
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern2
Patern1
line1
line2
..
linen
Patern2

Thank you
Utpal

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/408903)